# WITH ROLLUP is not calculating totals on some columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an SQL statement that gives a list of creditors on jobs.
In the example in the image both of creditors belong to the same job. 
So on the last row that is displaying the TOTALS the number of jobs is 1 which is correct because it is the same job. Also the columns that say NotPOD is also correct saying just 1. 
But for all the other columns it is adding the totals. Like the Column that says FL (it is a piece type). There is only 1 FL piece type on this job. But since the job has two creditors the total is displaying two even though only one exists.

[image]

I don't know how the totals are correct for jobs and NotPOD.

Here is the sql statement:

```sql
SET group_concat_max_len=10000000;
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
       'sum((select sum(jp1.AdvisedQty)
                from job_pieces jp1
                left join piecestype pt1 on jp1.TypeID = pt1.ID
                where jp1.jobid=jn.id and pt1.code=''', pt.Code , '''
            ))  AS `', pt.Code, '`'
    )
  ) into @sql
FROM creditor c
LEFT JOIN invoicedetail i on c.ID = i.creditorId
LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON i.JobID = jn.ID
LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON jp.JobID = jn.ID
LEFT JOIN piecestype pt on jp.TypeID = pt.ID
WHERE c.Company_ID = ?compid;

set @sql = concat('select 
        ifnull(c.Name,''TOTAL'') as Name,
        COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
        sum(case when (select count(jbs.status) from jobstat jbs
                where jbs.jobid=jn.id and jbs.Status=''DEL'')>0
                      then 1 else 0 end) as Delivered,
        sum(case when (select count(jbs.status) from jobstat jbs
                where jbs.jobid=jn.id and jbs.Status=''POD'')>0
                      then 1 else 0 end) as POD,
        SUM((select COUNT(ID) from job_debriefs
                WHERE JobID = jn.ID)) as Debriefs,
        sum(jn.OutTurn) as Outturn,
        SUM(jn.ActualWeight) as GrossWt,
        ', @sql, ' 
    FROM creditor c
    LEFT JOIN invoicedetail i on c.ID = i.creditorId
    LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON i.JobID = jn.ID
    LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON jp.JobID = jn.ID
    LEFT JOIN piecestype pt on jp.TypeID = pt.ID
    WHERE c.Company_ID = ', ?compid, GROUP BY c.Name WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Could you try to format the query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry what do you mean?

Comment: `SELECT @sql` at then end -- It may be helpful to see the SQL after all the games that are going on.

Comment: Please simplify the query down to, say, `jobs` and `FL`, which seems to be enough to show the problem??

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see `FL` anywhere in the sql??

Comment: Can you share the schema?

Answer (score 2):

The `with rollup`-flag will do different things when you use `count(distinct)` and `sum`.

For `COUNT(distinct jn.ID)` it will give you the number of distinct Jobids over all the displayed data. That is probably what you want.

For a sum-column like `sum(case...) as POD` it will just give you the sum over all displayed values - and POD would be "2", if the job had the status "POD".

As for the NotPOD-Column: I assume you just calcalute it in your client (maybe as Jobs - POD), and since POD was 0 (could have been 2 though), it looks fine. I assume you calculate "Units" in your client too (as the sum of the 4 piece types). If not, your code doesn't fit to your picture.

So how to fix it?

Well, basically you just can't use `with rollup`, mainly because you don't want to have the sums of the displayed values, and that is what `with rollup` is for.

The easiest solution is to calculate the total-row manually and merge them with `union`, e.g. something like this:

```
select c.Name as Name,
    COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
    ...
    sum(jn.OutTurn) as Outturn,
    SUM(jn.ActualWeight) as GrossWt,
    ...
    FROM creditor c
    LEFT JOIN invoicedetail i on c.ID = i.creditorId
    LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON i.JobID = jn.ID
    -- !!! DO NOT USE LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON jp.JobID = jn.ID !!!
    -- !!! DO NOT USE LEFT JOIN piecestype pt on jp.TypeID = pt.ID !!!
    WHERE c.Company_ID = ', ?compid, GROUP BY c.Name, '   
UNION
    ''Total'',
    COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
    ...
    sum(jn.OutTurn) as Outturn,
    SUM(jn.ActualWeight) as GrossWt,
    ...
    -- you have to figure out what number you need here for the pieces
    -- you probably want to seperate that part too (as you did with @sql)
    -- (select sum(jp1.AdvisedQty) from job_pieces jp1 ... )  as FL
    ... 
    from job_new jn 
    WHERE exists(select 1 
                 FROM creditor c
                 JOIN invoicedetail i on c.ID = i.creditorId
                 where i.JobID = jn.ID and c.Company_ID = ', ?compid, '
                )
```

No `group by` in the second part!
You have to figure out what values you want for the per-pieces-sums and you probably want to prepare them with a statement similarly to your `select
group_concat(distinct ...`

And a warning: if i understand your datamodel correctly, you absolutely have to remove the

```
LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON jp.JobID = jn.ID
LEFT JOIN piecestype pt on jp.TypeID = pt.ID
```

statements, because they will ruin your values when you have more then one jobpiece or piecetype in one job (you can try adding a 2nd value to a job and see that). And if it is possible that you have the same job twice on one `invoicedetail`, you have to fix that part too.

And beware that in the union-part, you cannot join over the customers (you would count everything several times).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem is because of your group by condition.

you perform  GROUP BY c.Name WITH ROLLUP and as far as I understand - your c.Name is the name of the creditor.

Try grouping by job id or other unique identifier of your record.

Comment: changing the GROUP BY returns the wrong data. If I use the Creditor ID or the job id then the results are wrong.

Comment: you have a lot of conditions in your query that is very hard to understand without seeing the data. the rollup works correctly as it should. you just need to perform a different calculation and not the `rollup`.  Can't help you more than that without a small dump of sample data.

Comment: but how is `rollup` working correcting with it says the total jobs is 1 but its adding all the other columns together? Is there a different way to calculate the totals on the bottom row without `rollup`?